# what is double fault ? how exactly is it related to stack overflow

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, operating-system

I am new at learning operating systems.I cannot find a proper description of this term on internet.Any help can be useful

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_fault

Comment: You clearly haven't looked very hard.

Comment: Googling 'OS double fault': 'About 1,660,000 results'.  This is plainly an attempt to get a unique homework answer written for free.

Comment: That wikipedia article is pretty lame and misleading. Sadly, the Intel documentation conflates interrupt, fault, and trap. That is reflected in that (and several other related Wikipedia articles).

Answer (score 3):

A fault is an exceptional condition detected by the CPU. In x86/64 a fault triggers an interrupt which instructs the CPU to pause what it's doing and execute an interrupt handler.

For example a divide by zero fault occurs when a process attempts to perform a division operation with zero as the divisor. When this happens the CPU pauses the process and runs to divide by zero handler. Usually this handler logs an error and kills the process.

A double fault occurs when a fault occurs when the CPU is running the handler for a fault. In this case the CPU pauses the execution of the fault handler and jumps to the double fault handler. A double fault is usually the result of a bug in the kernel.

A triple fault occurs when a fault is raised in the double fault handler. As far as I know this always halts the CPU causing a reboot.

EDIT: a double fault occurs when the CPU is unable to execute the interrupt service routine for a fault.

Comment: That's actually wrong: double fault occurs when _attempting to invoke_ an ISR, not while the latter is already running. Same for triple fault.